# Facebook Graph API - “get likes of a comment of a picture” query returns empty array

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hello Facebook gurus :)

I'd like some help on this one

This is a post I made on a picture and then I liked it:

```
{
"created_time" = "2011-06-07T23:23:19+0000";
from =     {
    id = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    name = "Adrien xxxxxxxx";
};
id = "107817942643477_24293";
likes = 1;
message = baar;
"user_likes" = 1;
}
```

I'm trying to get the userID's of friends/me who liked this comment I made on a picture

I made this :
https://graph.facebook.com/107817942643477_24293/likes?access_token=TOKEN

I tried too with Fql:

```
NSString *theQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT likes FROM stream WHERE post_id=\"%@\"", postID];
id theResult = [[AppDelegate sharedFacebook]
    sendSynchronousRequestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
    andParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    theQuery, @"query", nil]
    andHttpMethod:@"GET"];
```

It doesn't work, maybe because this comment is liked to a picture and I should format the request differently ?

The only thing I'm receiving is an empty array

```
{
data =     (
);
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance for any help on this one.

Ps: I'm using the iOS Facebook library, could it be broken ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the user id. Taking the example from the Facebook documentation here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

Click on the link there and add '/likes' before the query string containing the access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_475058873552_14173716/likes?access_token=2227470867|2.AQDprvRAYwU-6lHe.3600.1309028400.0-604597322|Z4r0uxTK5ctlAn5rbs2NUNYZr88
```

If you remove the user id from the id, however...

```
https://graph.facebook.com/475058873552_14173716/likes?access_token=2227470867|2.AQDprvRAYwU-6lHe.3600.1309028400.0-604597322|Z4r0uxTK5ctlAn5rbs2NUNYZr88
```

...it won't work.

So you need to manually add the user id to your comment id if it's not already present.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to accept it because you're right. But with the specific case of comments of images it's not working. If I have a comment on a picture It just looks like the <id of the picture>_<id of the comment> in the returned json, and a request to it's likes doesn't work. I tried to add my id like this <my ID>_<id of the picture>_<id of the comment> but it returns nothing. I'm afraid this is a limitation of the API. Thanks for you answer anyway.